# Need a PC monitoring software with alerts

Tags: windows, monitoring

I'm looking for a PC monitoring software that can monitor:

- Temperatures
- Voltages
- Fan speed

It also needs the ability to set maximum and minimum limits so that if a value goes above or below it then it will:

- Write a log
- If possible, send an email report
- If possible, start a sound (maybe a buzzer)

This software has to be compatible with Windows 7/8/10, Intel or AMD CPU, and Intel, Nvidia or AMD GPU.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

How do you plan on executing the monitor tool? This is my question, is this meant to be automatic or more a server monitor?

I do not believe of a current free program that accomplishes everything you have. It may be simpler to actually create jobs that start this for you. One of the better options I can provide to you is HWiNFO32/64, which can be downloaded [from here.](http://www.hwinfo.com/download.php) You can obtain HWiNFO32/64 Addons from this [website](http://www.hwinfo.com/addons.php).

**What is this program good for?**

This app allows you to monitor several items, such as

- CPU Temperature [Cores and Threads, Temperature]
- Memory [Memory Loads, Available etc.]
- GPU [Usage and Temperature]
- SSD/HDD [Read and Write Speeds and Activity]
- Network Activity

Here is an example SS of the application in process.

[image: Main Application GUI]

You have the unique ability to add explicit reporting to tray, meaning you can use icons to report on items individually.

Furthermore, installing the Rainmeter skin you can have outcomes like so:

[image: Rainmeter Skin on Desktop]

[image: Gadget]

Lastly this application allows you to output alerts to a CSV file for you to later use for report and analysis.

The last thing it does (which is what you require) is alerts:

[image: Alerting]

I believe this application meets all your requirements.